# Cloudformation script for AWS Codepipeline code commit, Code Build and Code Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am new to write cloudformation script so I am seeking help for writing a CF script for provisioning AWS CICD setup using codepipeline, code commit, code build and code deploy.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is two pre-build CloudFormation Script you can refer.

1. Unit test environment using CloudFormation: [Continuous Delivery of Nested AWS CloudFormation Stacks Using AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/continuous-delivery-of-nested-aws-cloudformation-stacks-using-aws-codepipeline/)  | [Github](https://github.com/awslabs/codepipeline-nested-cfn)
2. [AWS CI/CD Pipeline using CloudFromation](https://cloudonaut.io/aws-velocity-ci-cd-pipeline-as-code/)  | [Github](https://github.com/widdix/aws-velocity/)

Note: You can use [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) to build your CF script